# how to make the div above the input in this code

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

#### html

```
<div id="CldrFromSpan" messageHint="From">
    <input type="text" id="CldrFrom" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="From" style="width:15%"  />
</div>
```

#### css

```
#CldrFromSpan {
    display:inline;
}

#CldrFromSpan:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(messageHint);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}
```

when I hover over that div. I got this:

[image]

I need the message to be exactly above the input. can you help pelase?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKPW2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you an idea on how you could do it. The trick is giving the outer element `position:relative;` and the inner element `position:absolute;`.

A child element with position absolute will be positioned absolute to his next parent element with `position: relative;` in this case will the input be set to left:0px; top: -30px; from `<div>`

```
<div id="CldrFromSpan" messageHint="From">
    <input type="text" id="CldrFrom" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="From" style="width:15%"  />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKPW2/3/)

```
#CldrFromSpan {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#CldrFromSpan:hover:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left:0px;

    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(messageHint);
    padding: 5px 15px;

    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: You can't click on the text box with `bottom: 0px`, since the pop-up covers the box. Try using: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKPW2/2/).

Comment: @ReCaptcha true, I firefox there is a small 2px gab to click in, which isn't good so you're absolutly right, I din't even try to click in there. I think the questioner can figure out exactly how to place the hover box now

Comment: Updated the answer with a margin top, dipslay:inline-block; and postioned the element with top:-30px;